# How to assign clob data to java variable

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, clob

I am getting xml as CLOB data from database using JdbcTemplate-Spring Boot application. I assign the CLOB data to java variable which return as clob. But i want to read the xml . how ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Clob is not longer than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, you can simply extract the string from your Clob like this:

```
String string = clob.getSubString(1, (int) clob.length());
```